# Error in editing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This is showing an error, don't know why.

```
function display() {
 getMPS();
 getDMaxCost();
 getSMaxCost();
 getMMaxCost();

 var mps = document.getElementById("mps");
 mps.innerHTML("You are getting " + player.mps + " layers per second.");

 var money = document.getElementById("money");
 money.innerHTML(player.money);

 var dCost = document.getElementById("dCost");
 dCost.innerHTML("Cost: " + player.dCost);

 var dMax = document.getElementById("dMax");
 dMax.innerHTML("Max buy. Buying: " + player.dMaxAmt + ". Cost: " + 
 player.dMaxCost);

 var dAmt = document.getElementById("dAmount");
 dAmt.innerHTML(player.dAmount);

 var sCost = document.getElementById("sCost");
 sCost.innerHTML("Cost: " + player.sCost);

 var sMax = document.getElementById("sMax");
 sMax.innerHTML("Max buy. Buying: " + player.sMaxAmt + ". Cost: " + 
 player.sMaxCost);

 var sAmt = document.getElementById("sAmount");
 sAmt.innerHTML(player.sAmount);

 var mCost = document.getElementById("mCost");
 mCost.innerHTML("Cost: " + player.mCost); 

 var mMax = document.getElementById("mMax");
 mMax.innerHTML("Max buy. Buying: " + player.mMaxAmt + ". Cost: " + 
      player.mMaxCost);

 var mAmt = document.getElementById("mAmount");
 mAmt.innerHTML(player.mAmount);  
}
```

This is the error:

Uncaught TypeError: mps.innerHTML is not a function

I am attempting to change the text on the site of my game, would appreciate help. I don't know what other information to include, but I will include the link to the site if you need it.
https://merp101.github.io/

Please help me.

Comment: innerHTML is not a function. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is not a function, is an attribute, you should do

```
mps.innerHTML = "You are getting " + player.mps + " layers per second.";
```